# What is the difference between .zshrc and .zshrc-e

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh, dotfiles

I've recently switched to using zsh instead of bash and I installed both zsh and oh-my-zsh. while messing with my configuration I noticed that there is a file named ".zshrc-e" in addition to the typical ".zshrc". What's the difference and what is .zshrc-e used for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~/.zshrc` is zsh's user configuration for interactive shells. (actually it is `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`, but `HOME` is used if `ZDOTDIR` is unset)

`~/.zshrc-e` has no special meaning to zsh and is not used by it. Unless, of course, you load it somewhere in `~/.zshrc`. (If I had to guess, I would say it is probably just a backup/copy of `~/.zshrc`, but that is easy to check.)

Answer (score 6):

.zshrc-e means zshrc e(xample) file.